# Source script on interactive shell inside Docker container

Tags: bash, docker

I want to open a interactive shell which sources a script to use the bitbake environment on a repository that I bind mount:

```
docker run --rm -it \
--mount type=bind,source=$(MY_PATH),destination=/mnt/bb_repoistory  \
my_image /bin/bash -c "cd /mnt/bb_repoistory/oe-core && source build/conf/set_bb_env.sh"
```

The problem is that the `-it` argument does not seem to have any effect, since the shell exits right after executing `cd /mnt/bb_repoistory/oe-core && source build/conf/set_bb_env.sh`

I also tried this:

```
docker run --rm -it \
--mount type=bind,source=$(MY_PATH),destination=/mnt/bb_repoistory  \
my_image /bin/bash -c "cd /mnt/bb_repoistory/oe-core && source build/conf/set_bb_env.sh && bash"
```

Which spawns an interactive shell, but none of the macros defined in `set_bb_env.sh`

Would there be a way to provide a tty with the script properly sourcered ?

Comment: Have you tried `man bash`, specifically the documentation on bash's `-i` option and the INVOCATION section? The way you invoke bash, it is NOT interactive.

Comment: I have also tried `/bin/bash -ci` but no success. The behavior of adding the `-c` flag seems to always make the shell exit after executing the arguments between `'''`, regardless of other options also added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-it` flag is conflicting with the command to run in that you're telling docker to create the pseudo-terminal (ptty), and then running a command in that terminal (`bash -c ...`).  When that command finishes, then the run is done.

What some people have done to work around this is to only have `export` variables in their sourced environment, and the last command would be `exec bash`. But if you need aliases or other items that aren't inherited like that, then your options are a bit more limited.

Instead of running the source in a parent shell, you could run it in the target shell. If you modified your .bash_profile to include the following line:

```
[ -n "$DOCKER_LOAD_EXTRA" -a -r "$DOCKER_LOAD_EXTRA" ] && source "$DOCKER_LOAD_EXTRA”
```

and then had your command be:

```
... /bin/bash -c "cd /mnt/bb_repository/oe-core && DOCKER_LOAD_EXTRA=build/conf/set_bb_env.sh exec bash"
```

that may work. This tells your .bash_profile to load this file when the env variable is already set, but not otherwise. (There can also be the `-e` flag on the docker command line, but I think that sets it globally for the entire container, which is probably not what you want.)

Comment: That's a nice workaround. Since my container is ephemeral for now (`docker run --rm`), I'm editing my `.bashrc` directly on the run call: `... /bin/bash -c "echo 'source build/conf/set_bb_env.sh' >> ~/.bashrc && cd /mnt/bb_repository/oe-core && bash"`. It works just fine!

Comment: alternatively, you could use `bash`'s `--rcfile` option and potentially an embedded command substitution like so: `docker run --rm -it bash -c 'exec bash -i --rcfile <(cat <<< "cd /to/some/path && source another.sh")'`